# Face book application not reviewed successfully

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

I am developing a face book application where user will fetch wall,tagged,group and pages video. now its working fine on admin account, but it is not working on other account. I also submitted the application for review yesterday, but today i got the message (in the picture below).
[image]

Comment: The feedback in the "general" section is pretty clear - you need to demonstrate a real user environment. The Facebook team are definitely ok with approving staging websites/apps, as long as they appear to a real user interface.

Comment: @ChrisHoughton what do you mean by real user environment???

Comment: A real website or app. Is your site public?

Comment: @ChrisHoughton yes my application is public, i have set it as public